# Topology Question on a Particular Surface

Tags: general-topology

I have a following question that states:

> Let $T$ be (the surface of) my morning iced doughnut (a torus, not the jam-filled kind!).  For the purpose of this problem we shall assume that $T$ is symmetric with respect to a coordinate system whose origin is in the middle of the hole, so that if $x\in T$, then $-x\in T$ too.  Let $f(x) $ denote the depth of the icing at a point $x$ on $T$, a function which we shall assume to be continuous.
>
> Prove that these is a point $x$ on my doughnut at which $f(x) = f(-x)$.

[(original scan)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOOYI.png)

I am quite unsure of how to progress. My first problem is understanding the covering of the icing. Conventionally, icing only covers a particular part of the donut. Should I assume that? Am I working in 3 dimensions? That is, is my function one that $\mathbb{R^3} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$? This question is one that has been provided in my topology class, but I can't seem to bring topological concepts to light here. Is this torus homeomorphic to something that I can work with?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermediate value theorem suffices: Consider the function $g(x):=f(x)-f(-x)$ on $T$, which is continuous. If $g(x_0)\ne0$ at some point $x_0\in T$, say $g(x_0)>0$, then $g(-x_0)<0$. Since the surface $T$ is connected there is a continuous path $$\gamma: \quad [0,1]\to T,\qquad t\mapsto\gamma(t),$$ with $\gamma(0)=-x_0$, $\>\gamma(1)=x_0$. The pullback $$\phi(t):=g\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)$$ is continuous and satisfies 
$$\phi(0)=g(-x_0)<0,\quad \phi(1)=g(x_0)>0\ .$$Therefore $\phi(\tau)=0$ for some $\tau$ in the interval $\ ]0,1[\ $. Let $\xi:=\gamma(\tau)\in T$. As $g(\xi)=\phi(\tau)=0$ we have  $f(\xi)=f(-\xi)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble understanding your second last sentence. I believe you have used the IVT here, correct? In saying that if $g(a)<0<g(b)$ (is this obvious?), then there exist $\gamma (x) \in T$ such that $g(\gamma (t)) = 0$. I don't understand the establishment of the inequality. The rest follows understandably. Can you please elaborate? Thank you so much.

Comment: That's by the definition of the point $x_{0}$ and the definition of $g$. The proof chose $x_{0}$ so that $g(x_{0}) = f(x_{0}) - f(-x_{0}) > 0$. Then $g(-x_{0}) = f(-x_{0}) - f(x_{0}) = -g(x_{0}) < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The icing covers the entire donut, but if the depth of icing $f(x)$ is zero at some point $x$, you might imagine that there is no icing at $x$; in the context of the problem you're solving, it doesn't matter.

The function is $f:T\to [0,\infty)$.  It is defined only at each point of the surface of the donut (that is $T$, not all of $R^3$) and its value is a non-negative icing depth, which is a number that is at least $0$.

I think it might suffice to consider the largest circle around the outside of the donut, so you are ignoring all of $T$ except for a subset which is equal to $S^1$ and which is symmetric with respect to the origin.  Then I think the usual way to proceed is to let $g(x) = f(x)-f(-x)$ and show that there must be some $x$ for which $g(x)=0$.  Have you studied any fixed-point theorems?  These seem to be to be relevant here.